# If Image Width = 250 CSS

Tags: html, image, css

Is there a good CSS3 way of styling the img tag if it has a certain width without having to include a class to the image.
(Perhaps using something like the

```
@media
```

queries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `width` is specified in the HTML like :

```
<img src=".." width=250>
```

Then you can use this CSS :

```
img[width='250'] {
    /* style */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGRNz/1/)